# How do I show this is strictly positive without using matrices.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Suppose $ds^2 = Edu^2 + 2Fdudv + Gdv^2$ is the first fundamental form of some regular surface patch, show $EG - F^2 > 0$ for each point on the surface patch.

So technically I could put $E$, $F$, and $G$ into the metric tensor and define a surface patch $\sigma$ to find the determinant and show it is not $0$.

But the problem is that I want to find a way to show this is indeed strictly positive without refering to the surface patch $\sigma$. Is it possible to do this in terms only in $E$ , $F$, and $G$?

Comment: It is impossible because $E$, $F$ and $G$ are the components of the first fundamental form in a coordinate patch $(u,v)$

Comment: Impossible as in, it is not possible to prove it without referring it to the surface patch $\sigam$?

Comment: To be honest, your question is not clear to me. Do you want to prove that the first fundamental form is positive definite in a coordinate-free manner? When I said "impossible" I meant that in the form as the problem is stated this is, probably, not expected. Of course, one can show this in an invariant way, but using a different notation...

Comment: Yes. I want to prove that the first fundamental form is positive definite in a coordinate free manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the answer is in a sense completely obvious, I have to admit that the question is good, because it checks the understanding.

**Answer**. The first fundamental form (a.k.a. the induced metric) is positive-definite because the metric in the background space is assumed to be positive-definite, and on the vectors tangential to the surface both metrics have the same value *by definition*.

**Explanations**. I decided to add a few lines to exhibit the context. So, let $f \colon U \to \Bbb R^3$ be a parametrization of a regular surface $S_f$. Regularity means that $\mathrm{d}f$ is injective. Denote by $G$ the inner product in $\Bbb R^3$ (usually $G$ is taken to be the Euclidean metric). The first fundamental form of the surface $S_f$ is defined by its action on the vectors $X$ and $Y$ tangent to the surface as
$$
g(X,Y) := G(\mathrm{d}f(X), \mathrm{d}f(Y))
$$
Looking at this definition one can immediately convince themselves that the first fundamental form is positive definite.